# How to find middle element of doubly linked list using head and tail?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Is there a way possible to find the middle element of a doubly linked list using head and tail. I tried traversing to the next element from the starting node and the previous element from the end node and check if the reference of both is same or not. This works fine if there are odd number of elements in the list. I am not able to find when should I stop in case the number of elements in the list is even.

```
while(head.next != end.previous) {
    head = head.next;
    end = end.previous;
}
```

Comment: Which/where are the pointers to your doubly linked list?

Comment: n/2 can be the mid of the list.

Comment: If the number of nodes be even, then there is no middle node.  The best you can do is to report two nodes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: How do we get those nodes?

Comment: Also, there is another problem here.  If two nodes are storing the exact same object, then their references might be equal.  So even for an odd list your algorithm could fail.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Thanks! Got it. Yes, that will also be a problem. I know how to find it with a single iteration. Was curious if I can use the end pointer as well to reduce the iterations.

Comment: If the references are all guaranteed to be unique, then what you describe should work.

Comment: But it works only if the number of elements is add. In even case the pointers passes over each other.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is:

Start with a pointer x at the beginning and a pointer y at the end. Repeatedly execute the following steps:

1. If x=y, stop.
2. Advance x forward.
3. If x=y, stop.
4. Advance y backward.

This should work out for both even and odd length. But it also needs 2 comparisons and an assumption that all the references will be unique.